# React Native dynamic - List view from Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am getting started with react native, hope some one can help me with the small issue that I am facing.

So I have a primary api with all the stores names and ID, basically all want to do is load the top bar of the react native app with Store names and 
extract the ID and attach it to the Store links and Generate it to the list view.

So far I was only able to attach the store names from the the REST Api link, but I cannot add the List view.

My goal is to use one class file and populate all individual tabs with different store content.
Code below

```
const STARTUPLINK = "https//staruptest.com/defaultStartup";
const STORE_URL = "https//staruptest.com/store/mobile&id=";


     class Shop1 extends Component{
       render() {
         return(
            //STORE_URL+ID
          //Listview 
         );
       }
     }

  class Shop2 extends Component{
       render() {
         return(
            //STORE_URL+ID
          //Listview 
         );
       }
     }

  class Shop3 extends Component{
       render() {
         return(
            //STORE_URL+ID
          //Listview 
         );
       }
     }

  class Shop4 extends Component{
       render() {
         return(
            //STORE_URL+ID
          //Listview 
         );
       }
     }


 const components = {
   // only works when shop name matches the componet name 
  Shop1, Shop2, Shop3,Shop4
  //
}


export default class TopNavigationTabs extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(STARTUPLINK).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      const screens = {};
      const ShopURL={};
      res.shops.forEach(shops => {
        screens[shops.name] = { screen: components[shops.name],
          navigationOptions: { 
            title: shops.name ,
                    tabBarOptions: {
                        scrollEnabled: true,
                        labelStyle: {fontSize: 10},

                    tabStyle:{width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 4,},
                    style: {backgroundColor: '#0C84D8',},
                    indicatorStyle: {backgroundColor: '#fff',}
                },}};  
                console.log(shops.name)
                console.log(STORE_URL+shops.id)
      }); 
      const tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(screens)
      this.setState({ tabs: tabs });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.tabs) {
      return (<this.state.tabs />);
    } 
    return (

      <View>
        <Text> Loading ... </Text>
        </View>

    )
  }
}
```

So instead of using Store1, Store2, Store3, mounting on Components
I need one class which can generate the content dynamically across all tabs, so one store gets disables on the Api, it will get automatically removed from the app.

whats working: Tab names are pulling from the Api and populating, without any issues, just the content inside each tab according to different Store id links.

I am just starting with react native,
Any help is much appreciated.